# Mapping data from two arrays which have different lengths and creating another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two arrays which have two different lengths.
For example:

```
var array1 = [{name: 'Yuri', age: 2, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Akit', age: 19, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Kean', age: 14, gender: 'Female'}, {name: 'Jan', age: 29, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Max', age: 25, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Suzy', age: 20, gender: 'Female'}];
var array2 = [{name: 'Jan', gender: 'Male', occupation: 'Designer'}, {name: 'Max', gender: 'Male', occupation: 'Developer'}, {name: 'Suzy', gender: 'Female', occupation: 'Tester'}];
```

`array1`'s length is 5 and  `array2`'s length is 3. I want to run a loop on both arrays and match the name. If the name matches then I want to extract the that particular object from 2nd array. As they have different lengths loop is breaking at the first array length and not reaching 2nd array's last element. I am running the for loop based on array2 length. Please help me with this.

Expected result:
Name of both arrays should be matched and create another array as below

`var array3 = [{name: 'Jan',age: 29, gender: 'Male', occupation: 'Designer'},`

same for other objects]

Comment: please add the wanted result and the code, you tried. btw, the first and second is switched ...

Comment: first array is of length 5 and also please share expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for one array's names and filter the second array.

```js
var array1 = [{name: 'Yuri', age: 9, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Akit', age: 19, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Kean', age: 14, gender: 'Female'}, {name: 'Jan', gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Max', gender: 'Female'}],
    array2 = [{name: 'Jan', age: 9, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Max', age: 19, gender: 'Male'}, {name: 'Suzy', age: 14, gender: 'Female'}],
    set2 = new Set(array2.map(({ name }) => name)),
    result = array1.filter(o => set2.has(o.name));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can you please explain this line: `set2 = new Set(array2.map(({ name }) => name))`

Comment: @DanielB., the inner part maps only the names by using a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and uses them as a `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr1 = [{name: 'Jan', age: 19}, {name: 'Suzy', age: 29}, {name: 'Peter', age: 39}, {name: 'Bart', age: 49}, {name: 'John', age: 59}];
var arr2 = [{name:'Kean', job: 'Technician'},{name:'Nick', job:'Mathematics'},{name: 'Jan', job: 'Tester'}, {name: 'Suzy', job:'Developer'}, {name: 'Peter', job: 'Scrum master'}];


result = arr1.map(x=> {
 y = arr2.find(z=> x.name == z.name);
 x.job = y ? y.job : undefined;
 return x;
});
```