# Comparing the properties of objects of two arrays and storing it in a new array

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare a property of an object of two arrays of different lengths. If my condition is true (gender check) and then if that property matches then I would like to combine the properties of that object from both arrays and store it in a different array.

For example:

```
// array 1
var array1 = [{name: 'Jan', age: 19, category: {gender: 'Male'}}, {name: 'Suzy', age: 29, category: {gender: 'Female'}}, {name: 'Peter', age: 39, category: {gender: 'Male'}}, {name: 'Bart', age: 49, category: {gender: 'Male'}}, {name: 'John', age: 59, category: {gender: 'Male'}}];
// array 2
var array2 = [{name:'Kean', job: 'Technician'},{name:'Nick', job:'Mathematics'},{name: 'Jan', job: 'Tester'}, {name: 'Suzy', job:'Developer'}, {name: 'Peter', job: 'Scrum master'}]
```

Expected result:

```
var resultMale = [{name: 'Jan', age: 19,job: 'Tester'}, {name: 'Peter', age: 39, job: 'Scrum master'}];
var resultFemale = [{name: 'Suzy', age: 29, job:'Developer'}];
```

Below is my attempt just to show that I have been putting all my effort to find a solution myself. I have changed all the functions and variable names
this.

```
xxxxxxxx.getContractsForRules().then(res => {
        // res.xxxxxx.forEach(function (obj) {
        //     if(obj.contract.product.xxxxxxx=== 'xxxxxxx') {
        //         console.log(this.xxxxxx.xx);
        //         for(let i=0; i < this.xxxxxxx.length; i++) {
        //             if(obj.contract.accountNumber === this.xxxxxxxx[i].ibanNumber) {
        //                 this.currentAccount = {
        //                     accountNumber: res.xxxxx[i].contract.accountNumber,
        //                     accountName: res.xxxxx[i].contract.customer.xxxxxx
        //                 };
        //                 this.xxxxxxx.push(this.xxxxxx);
        //             }
        //         };
        //     }
        // });

        this.result = res.contractList.filter(item => this.allCurrentAccounts.);

            if(res.xxxx[i].contract.xxxxx=== this.xxxxx[i].ibanNumber) {
                this.savingAccount = {
                    accountNumber: xxxx.xxxx[i].contract.accountNumber,
                    accountName: res.xxxxx[i].contract.customer.xxxxx
                };
                this.xxxxx.push(this.xxxxx);
            }

    });
    this.test();
}
```

Comment: Apart from that you again show no own efforts whatsoever, this seems to be pretty much a duplicate of your own previous question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071551/

Comment: You need to add the code you've attempted to your question. SO is a site for asking for help with _your code_, not a site for asking people to do all the coding for you.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please share your attempt so far? You can do what you are trying to by trivially combining the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach), [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) methods. You cal also [check this guide out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to ask questions better on SO

Comment: I couldn't frame my question correctly in my previous question so I was getting irrelevant answers so I thought of framing a clear question in a new thread

Comment: You will find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We need to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @Andy I am using this site to learn things. I have been trying for this since yesterday. I am confused with the forEach, reduce, filter and other stuff. I am not able to pick up easily. If you can answer please do it so that you can teach someone like me or there is no pressure on you to do so. Thanks for your reply. Also, I can't add my project code here so I created a mock data and posted

Comment: While that's one of the side benefits of the site, Stackoverflow is about answering questions about _code you've written_. There are lots of places on the net that have JavaScript tutorials if you're stuck of any of the methods you've mentioned.

Comment: the given data looks like teo different problems. would you like to combine diiferent length arrays or split a single array into two or more, depending on a property's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you finally need is an *Intersection* of both the arrays. So, you could do the following -

```js
var array1 = [{ name: 'Jan', age: 19, category: { gender: 'Male' } }, { name: 'Suzy', age: 29, category: { gender: 'Female' } }, { name: 'Peter', age: 39, category: { gender: 'Male' } }, { name: 'Bart', age: 49, category: { gender: 'Male' } }, { name: 'John', age: 59, category: { gender: 'Male' } }];

var array2 = [{ name: 'Kean', job: 'Technician' }, { name: 'Nick', job: 'Mathematics' }, { name: 'Jan', job: 'Tester' }, { name: 'Suzy', job: 'Developer' }, { name: 'Peter', job: 'Scrum master' }];

// Empty arrays to contain final intersection array for both male & females
var resultMale = [], resultFemale = [];

/* now looping over both arrays to traverse all the elements from them */

// iterating over first array
array1.forEach(x => {
// iterating over second array
array2.forEach(y => {
    // collect the objects only if the name attribute matches in both
    if (x.name == y.name) {
        // push into male array if gender is male else push into female array
        if (x.category && x.category['gender'] == 'Male') {
            resultMale.push({
                name: x.name,
                age: x.age,
                job: y.job
            });
        } else if (x.category && x.category['gender'] == 'Female') {
            resultFemale.push({
                name: x.name,
                age: x.age,
                job: y.job
            });
        }
    }
});
});

console.log(resultMale);
console.log(resultFemale);
```

**Note -** *this can be optimized to reduce the time complexity.*

Comment: The OP doesn't know any JS. If you're going to write this answer you should add commentary to explain what it does.

Comment: I gave you the reason.